# Chek array if has ID in DB do update else do insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I send input values with same names in array(ID inside) by post as it shown bellow

```
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" name="formetn" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="videolinks[<?php echo $videoid; ?>]" value="<?php echo $videolink; ?>" class="form-control">
</form
```

Here I am getting array and parse it

```
if(isset($_POST["hidden_input_name"]) && $_POST["hidden_input_name"]!="") 
{
  $ppp = $_POST['videolinks'];

  $arraylength = count($ppp);     //here i got count of sent items

  $ids = implode(",",array_keys($ppp));         //here I parse keys
  $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($ppp));
  $values  = implode(",", $escaped_values);      //here I parse values
}
```

Now I need to check if i have same ID in my table--> do **update of this row** 
If it is new ID --> do **Insert this row**

```
for($i = 0; $i < $arraylength; $i++)
{
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectvidelink))
  {
    $videoid  = $row["ID"];
  if ($videoid == key($ppp)) 
  {
   //do update of this row
  }
  else
  {
   //do insert of this row
  }
 }
}
```

I know that I do wrong smth, but do not know what exactly I should change to check array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST["videolinksecret"]) && $_POST["videolinksecret"]!="" && ($_POST["videolinksecret"]) === "baisdbsdvSuvhs7634bHv73bnjonasecret")
{
$conn = connect_to_bd();
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

//var_dump($_POST['videolinks']);

$fullarray = $_POST['videolinks'];

 foreach($fullarray as $key => $value) 
 {
  $query = "select * from videolink where id=$key";
  $pp = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($pp)){
    $dd = "update videolink set `videolink`='$value' where id=$key";
  }
  else{
    $dd = "insert into videolink(`videolink`) values('$value')";
  }
  $videolinkupdate = mysqli_query($conn,$dd);
  //echo "$key is at $value";
 }
 if($videolinkupdate)
 {
  echo $alertx='<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id = "successupdate" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Kapat"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong>
         </div>';
 }
  else
 {
  echo $alertx='<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id = "successupdate" role="alert">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Kapat"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <strong>ERROR!</strong> ERROR 03! 
    </div>';
 }
 
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" name="formetn" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="text" name="videolinks[<?php echo $videoid; ?>]" value="<?php echo $videolink; ?>" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="btnformetn" class="btn btn-md btn-success pull-right">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

u'd better do it on mysql side. get more info about `insert on duplicate key update` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Good idea, but I want to learn the way to do it by PHP first.

Comment: That`s exactly what i am trying to do now. Still i think it is not good way

Comment: why d u think so?:)

Comment: Maybe because i want to learn this way :D i will try to finish and will post my answer here)